Flaws with Git diff of Jupyter book in Visual Studio Code

It does not allow Stage selected ranges
When we deselect Show Output Differences , Show Next Change moves across output differences also...

Are these genuine flaws or do they have some workarounds ?

It's unclear what you're asking. Perhaps if you provided some screenshots that would help.
